# How to add a prefix random number to cell having email id in ms excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

i have some automation code which picks email ids from an excel. I dont want to go and change the email ids manually every time. So i decided to add a random number.
Here's what am doing:

1.select the set of cells.
2.click on conditional formatting
3.click on new rule
4.select format only cells that contain a value
5.then i edit rule description to cell value between 1 and 1000.
6.then select format and select general and say ok.

But i dont see random numbers being generated, Please suggest me a way to add random number to email ids.
[Here is my excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VgY1.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As the name suggests, conditional formatting only changes the formatting of the cell if a specified condition is met. It does not generate random numbers. Use the RAND or RANDBETWEEN to generate the random numbers. I am not sure how feasible this might be using your data as the above functions as volatile. The random figure will change every time you make a change in your worksheet, though you can paste it as values after generating the same. This will also require the use of a helper column and concatenation (to join the random number with the email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use conditional formatting for this. Conditional formatting will only format the cells, not change the content.

This can be solved without VBA. In a new column, add the following formula to generate a random number between 0 and 10 for any number 5:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,5,ROUND(RAND()*10,0))
```

or

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,5,RANDBETWEEN(0,10))
```

You may want to disable automatic calculation in the sheet (which is done in the Formulas tab) to avoid that the numbers are regenerated all the time. You may want to copy paste as values to keep the new values.

Comment: @Mehek - The answer is given by user8053786 not me.